# Sphinx - Add weight for geodistance

Tags: geolocation, sphinx

I use Sphinx for searching, with the php api and I want to attribute weight for geodistance.
For example :
0 to 5 miles => +100
6 to 20 miles => +50
etc

Do you know how can I do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic plan:

```
$->setSelect("*, IF(@grodist<20000,50,0)+IF(@grodist<5000,50,0)+@weight AS myweight");
$->setSortMod(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED,'myweight DESC');
```

(the exact syntax will depend on exactly how you using sphinx)

... also look at the INTERVAL() function - useful if have lots of intervals...